# Android looping infinite ListView?

Tags: android, user-interface, listview, loops, infinite

I'd like to make a looping ListView. That means, it behaves a bit like the picker widget on iOs, so when the user scrolls either up or down, the list just keeps looping its contents. I'd guess that one needs to write some fancy custom adapter for this, but I'm not sure if it's possible.

Afaik, the ListView needs to know the number of elements containted in the adapter in advance. That would be a problem in this case, for example.

Do you have any tips on this matter?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried returning 1000000 for `getCount` in your custom adapter, then set the listview to start scrolling in the middle and in every `getView` return the view which is appropriate to the virtual position? Remove scrollbars.. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean a circular ListView? A similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview) has been asked in the past.