# Android listview (array adapter) custom scrolling

Tags: android, listview, scroll

I would like to change the default behaviour of my listview, so when im scrolling to the last item, the list will keep scrolling untill the last item is at the top of the list.

default behaviour stops scrolling when the last item is fully in view.

Any ideas on how i can go about this pre 2.3?

Thanks,
   Totem.

Comment: This question has a couple interesting solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview

Comment: This isnt the solution im looking for, i just want to control the scroll not create a circular list, in order to change scrolling with this solution i would have to actuall add items to the adapter in order to make it scroll (i could add an item just for padding at the bottom but this is a very bad solution), the solution im looking for will probably be in the listview itself and not the adapter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone is interested in the solutions available it either:

1) add to the list view padding, that solution forces you to play around with the fading edge property since it gets sifted because of thee padding. also this method might not work well if your using a transparent background because items will be rendered and visible under the padding area. Although this could be fixed by entering the list into a relative layout and making sure to draw something over that area.

2) add transparent items to the listview for offset and not set them as enabled to avoid dividers, just need to make sure to change getItemCount and getItemTypeCount and so on if your if your item isn't really inside your adapter as per my case.

I went with option two.

Thanks,
   Totem.