# Android Loop List Adapter

Tags: android, listview, adapter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to create a closed (circular) ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview)

I would like to develop a listview which can loop the elements such as,

if the listview detected is the end element, then it will get the first element at the end.
"1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5......."

if the listview detected is the first element, then it will get the end element at the top.
"6,7,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,1,2,3,4,5......"

I found that has some solutions about the circular listview, but I think it is not fit for my case.

Is it possible to implement the looping adapter on android?

Comment: But the solutions always set the Integer.MAX_VALUE. I don't wanna set the limit because I want the list can looping no matter I am scrolling  to top / down.

Comment: How long will it take you to scroll through several billion items? I unless you plan on scrolling for a week straight (or maybe longer?) I think Integer.MAX_VALUE will work just fine.

Comment: I don't know how long will it scroll..., because I should be implement it can scroll in a loop automatically.

Comment: thats what it does.. why don't you try it and see if it works for you.. should take all of about 20 minutes to implement.

Comment: @Rebecca: Better you try to add and remove items when u scroll(means-> when u reach extreme end of right means add first items simultaneously remove first child,like this process for left scroll too.

Comment: @Rebecca: Have u got idea?Do u implemented that..Let me know once