# Coverflow : To Do Infinite Loop (Like Launcher, Can Go Back to First Item When Reach Last Item)

Tags: android, loops, user-interface, coverflow

CoverFlow is an implementation of gallery widget.

picture : http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_UW2f-eaiXZs/S4lCNH-wpyI/AAAAAAAAAJE/0Ce8jGe8fSA/s200/coverflowv2.png

It works like album cover when you are using music player in android or iOS.

Based on this url > http://www.inter-fuser.com/2010/02/android-coverflow-widget-v2.html ,
I implement coverflow for my project as a main menu UI and I'm having issues on how to make the item loop back to the first item when reached last item.

What i mean by infinite loop is, for example : if coverflow has 5 item, then when the app start, the centre of screen would show the item #3. when I swipe to right 2 times, i will find the last item is on the right and cannot swipe to the right anymore because no more item is provided. what i want is it able to loop back to item #1 and so on.

Example, here we have five item[1] [2] [3] [4] [5]

Illustration (the items - Please imagine it shows on the sceen):
When The first start, the UI shown will be

2] [3] [4 -- (5 is waiting to be shown)

When I swipe to the right once, it will show

3] [4] [5 -- (no other item to be shown after 5)

When I swipe to right once more :

4] [5] -- (no item more so it will display blank after 5)

What I want is :

4] [5] [1 -- (2 is waiting)

5] [1] [2 -- (3 is waiting

I want it to work both ways (move right : last item to first item, move left : first item to last item).
Really need an idea to work on this. Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the answer to [How to create a closed (circular) ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview). You can probably use a similar concept with the adapter feeding your coverflow view.