# Android - Circular array display

Tags: java, android, arrays, algorithm

I have a array of cities -

```
String[] cities = { "Riyadh", "Jubail", "Jeddah", "Madinah",
        "Tabuk","Bangalore","Chennai","Pune" };
```

I am displaying them in a list that has **three textview**(*fixed*) .
 This means we are  going to display three cities at a time.
 Here is the method to display the cities.

```
void setUpCityList(int iCity) {
    tvOneCity.setText(cities[iCity]);
    tvTwoCity.setText(cities[iCity + 1]);
    tvThreeCity.setText(cities[iCity + 2]);
}
```

When the user swipes up ,i am **incrementing** the index and the user swipes down i am **decrementing** the index.

```
void swipeUp()
{
    iCity++;
    setUpCityList(iCity);
}

void swipeDown()
{
    iCity--;
    setUpCityList(iCity);
}
```

I want to give this list a endless scroll functionality . 
That means if the user swipes up - and list reaches the last three elements , it should again start from first element.

Example -
 1. Current display - Last three elements - **"Bangalore","Chennai","Pune"** 

 2. Swipe up -- Display should be - **Chennai , Pune , Riyadh**

How can i achieve this functionality .
This is more of a programming question .
Any Help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview

Comment: Check this post on Stack Overflow :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080811/android-endless-list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to change the indexing in your method:

```
void setUpCityList(int iCity) {
    int length = cities.length;   

    tvOneCity.setText(cities[iCity % length]);
    tvTwoCity.setText(cities[(iCity + 1) % length]);
    tvThreeCity.setText(cities[(iCity + 2) % length]);
}
```

Once the `iCity` or `iCity + 1`, etc, reaches the `length`, actual index will automatically become `0`. And for values less than length, it will behave normally, as if there was no `modulus` operator.

This way you can create a cycle of as much item you want. So, it's a generalized and extensible solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
void swipeUp()
{   if(iCity == cities.length()){
        iCity = 0;
        setUpCityList(iCity++);

    }
    else{
        iCity++;
        setUpCityList(iCity);
    }
}
```

Try something like this.

Comment: And what if `iCity + 1 == cities.length()`?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
void swipeUp()
{
iCity++;
if ( iCity > urMaxlength){
   iCity =0;
}
setUpCityList(iCity);
}

void swipeDown()
{
iCity--;
if ( iCity < urMinlength){
   iCity =urMaxlength;
}
setUpCityList(iCity);
}
```

Comment: What if `iCity == maxLength - 1`? In that case, `iCity + 2` will be out of bounds.