# How to smoothly scroll to clicked item to top of RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a list of item as RecyclerView (expandable item) and I want to the item on list was moved/scrolled smoothly when clicked.

So let say that I have list as below on first screen and I click item "value 6". I want to achieve situation on second screen by smoothly scroll item "value 6" to top.

[image] [image]

My Layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my actual Adapter (it's inner class in ScrollingActivity which is for Google sample)

```
   public class Adapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<Adapter.ItemHolder> {

        Container[] values;

        public Adapter() {
            values = new Container[100];
            for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                values[i] = new Container();
                values[i].text = "value " + i;
            }

        }

        @Override
        public ItemHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new ItemHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(ItemHolder holder, int position) {
            holder.text.setText(values[position].text);
            holder.more.setVisibility(values[position].visibility);
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return values.length;
        }

        public class ItemHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

            private final TextView more; //it is expandable part
            TextView text;                

            public ItemHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                text = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
                more = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.more);

                text.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        int pos = getAdapterPosition();
                        if (more.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                            more.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            values[pos].visibility = View.GONE;
                        } else {
                            more.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            values[pos].visibility = View.VISIBLE;

                            int vfpos = linearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                            int d = pos - vfpos;
                            recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos);
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
         }
    }
```

So what I miss? 
I suppose that `recyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(pos)` do nothing because this item is actual on screen. But how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

I tried editing the answer from [Move/scroll clicked listitem view at top of screen in the expandablelistview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482888/move-scroll-clicked-listitem-view-at-top-of-screen-in-the-expandablelistview/18195444#18195444) for my Expandable RecyclerView, and it works.

onLayoutExpanded() is just an abstract method that is called when the view is expanded.

```
recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(this, recyclerData) {
    @Override
    public void onLayoutExpanded(int position) {
        int offset = position - recyclerLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();
        if (recyclerLayoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition() > 0) offset -= 1;
        recyclerLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(position, offset);
    }
};
```