# Go to last item of listview when scrolled up from the first item

Tags: android, listview

i have to make a closed circular list view. the list view moves down infinite times by using

```
 @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    }
```

but i need to got to the last item of the list when scrolled up so that a it feels as a circular list.

i tried `ListView.setSelection(1+(arraylist.size()*100));` but it dosint work as soon as the adapter is set. it only works when set as

```
circularListAdapter = new CircularListAdapter(adapter);
        threeDListView.setAdapter(circularListAdapter);
    Handler handler1 = new Handler();
            handler1.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {


                    threeDListView.setSelection(1+(smpl.size()*100));
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            },1500);
```

when the delay is less than 1500 it doesn't work. this delay cause the list to jump one sec after the list is displayed. is there any other way to scroll to the last item from the first item?

Comment: Instead of worrying about this yourself, check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4940073/2544584 Goodluck!

Comment: but in this case too i have to set a delay or it wont work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
threeDListView.setItemChecked(position, true);
threeDListView.smoothScrollToPosition(position);
```

This makes your ListView animate and move to any position selected.