# How to implement a ListView with repeated items?

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make a ListView with known items. All items are already in an ArrayList.

I keep track of hitting bottom in onScrollListener (onScroll method) and do this;

```
if(firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount >= totalItemCount)
    // move first item to end of arraylist
```

Problem is; when scroll is in the bottom, newly added items are shown instantly. What I want to do is keeping the same visible items on screen. Show new items if only scrolled.

I just want to repeat same items but couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list is scrolled to position `totalItemCount`.  If you simply change the order of the items in your list so the first item is at the end, it will display the new order but keep the position, so you will continue seeing the last item - whatever that is now.

It sounds like what you want is a circular scrolling ListView.  Try this solution: [Circular scrolling listview](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4940073/850734)

Comment: Thanks, "circular" was the word I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

Basicly, you can implement a simple listView in your activity, but using a special BaseAdapter that you create yourself (extented from BaseAdapter).

You can you something like this which takes as second parameter your list:

```
    package com.example.joignabilite;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

    public class ContactAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        // The list of contact
        private List<Contact> mListP;

        //COntexte of the adapter
        private Context mContext;

        //Mecanism to manage graphism from xml file
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        private int white = 0xFFFFFFFF;
        private int grey = 0x33000000;

        public ContactAdapter(Context context, List<Contact> aListP) {
              mContext = context;
              mListP = aListP;
              mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            }

        public int getCount() {
              return mListP.size();
            }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
              return mListP.get(position);
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
              return position;
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                  LinearLayout layoutItem;
                  //(1) : Réutilisation des layouts
                  if (convertView == null) {
                    //Initialisation de notre item à partir du  layout XML "Contact_layout.xml"
                    layoutItem = (LinearLayout) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_contact, parent, false);
                  } else {
                    layoutItem = (LinearLayout) convertView;
                  }

                  //(2) : Récupération des TextView de notre layout      
                  TextView tv_Nom = (TextView)layoutItem.findViewById(R.id.repertoire_item);

                  //(3) : Renseignement des valeurs       
                  tv_Nom.setText(mListP.get(position).nom);

                  //On mémorise la position de la "Contact" dans le composant textview
                  tv_Nom.setTag(position);        

                  if(position % 2 == 0)
                      layoutItem.setBackgroundColor(grey);
                  else
                      layoutItem.setBackgroundColor(white);

                  //On ajoute un listener
                  tv_Nom.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Lorsque l'on clique sur le nom, on récupère la position du "Contact"
                        Integer position = (Integer)v.getTag();

                        //On prévient les listeners qu'il y a eu un clic sur le TextView "TV_Nom".
                        sendListener(mListP.get(position), position);

                    }

                  });

                  //On retourne l'item créé.
                  return layoutItem;
                }   

            /**
             * Interface pour écouter les évènements sur le nom d'une Contact
             */
            public interface ContactAdapterListener {
                public void onClickNom(Contact item, int position);
            }

            //Contient la liste des listeners
            private ArrayList<ContactAdapterListener> mListListener = new ArrayList<ContactAdapterListener>();
            /**
             * Pour ajouter un listener sur notre adapter
             */
            public void addListener(ContactAdapterListener aListener) {
                mListListener.add(aListener);
            }

            private void sendListener(Contact item, int position) {
                for(int i = mListListener.size()-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    mListListener.get(i).onClickNom(item, position);
                }
            }

    }
```

Comment: And you could put it visible or not using the position part.