# Circular vertical viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

Displaying images in `viewpager vertically  and even looping`, like: **A>B>C>D>A** and on click of particular image need to open related site within browser.

Yet I achieved vertical view pager, with the help of [this tutorial](https://github.com/LambergaR/VerticalViewPager/) and looping is also working but onClick of image its not returning correct position its because of *getCount()* which I increment everytime within on instantiateItem. `If I wont do so then it stop looping.`

need to fetch correct position while I click on particular image, have a look at logic and suggest me.

*Adapter*

```
public class FullScreenImageAdapter extends com.xxxxxx.util.PagerAdapter {

    private Activity _activity;
    private ArrayList<String> _imagePaths;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int mFakeCount = 0,newPosition;

    // constructor
    public FullScreenImageAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> imagePaths) {
        this._activity = activity;
        this._imagePaths = imagePaths;
        mFakeCount = _imagePaths.size()+1;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.mFakeCount;
//      return this._imagePaths.size();
    }

    public int getNewPosition(){
        return newPosition;
    }


    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return view == ((RelativeLayout) object);
    }



    // image lenght =6
    //
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        ImageView imgDisplay;

             if (position >= _imagePaths.size()-1) { 
                  newPosition = position%_imagePaths.size();
                 Log.d("####", "new position="+newPosition);
                    position = newPosition;
                    mFakeCount++;
             }

             Log.d("####", "default position="+position);

        inflater = (LayoutInflater) _activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View viewLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_image, container,false);
        imgDisplay = (ImageView) viewLayout.findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(_imagePaths.get(position));
        imgDisplay.setImageBitmap(bitmap);



        ((VerticalViewPager) container).addView(viewLayout);
        viewLayout.setTag(_imagePaths.get(position));

        return viewLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        ((VerticalViewPager) container).removeView((RelativeLayout) object);

    }



}
```

*OnPageChangeListener*

```
_viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                browser_url = LockScreen.db.getURL("browser_url",_viewPager.getCurrentItem() + 1); //_viewPager.getCurrentItem() return wrong position.
                Log.i("browser_url dynamic", browser_url);
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset,
                    int positionOffsetPixels) 
            {


            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int position) {
                Log.v("onPageScrollStateChanged", String.valueOf(position));

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this code inside `onpageselected method:`

```
if (position < ImagepathList.size()) {
                   newPos = position;
                } else {
                for (int j = 0; j < ImagepathList.size(); j++) {
                    if (position % ImagepathList.size() == j) {
                        newPos = j;
                    }
                }
```

you will get correct position.

Comment: This works, but is bar far not an ideal solution. The whole `ViewPager` should be reworked, to only hold count + 2 items! If the user scrolls a lot, your app will crash, because there are to many items in the `ViewPager`.

Answer (score 1):

Vertical scroll ? Perhaps ListView is a better option.

Try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview), I think it could help.

Comment: Its not helpful in my case.

Answer (score 0):

This solution sounds simple, but does require some work to implement.

You are currently always increasing the count of items in the `ViewPager`, this does work to some extend, but isn't a good solution, it's a hack. 
You have to set the position back to the start position, when you are about to reach the end. For this you need a buffer of one item at the start and the end. 
The `ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener` and `onPageScrollStateChanged(int state)` are very useful (and required).

Now you can easily get the correct position, because you don't increase the count.

Comment: and what will happen when user will swipe `Up`.