# Closed or circular Horizontal ListView Android

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have an **Horizontal listview** i want listview should be closed. For example if the last item is reached in `Listview` then show the first item below the last item. It means item should be in circular format. And if i scroll from first item it should show last item before first item. I want **scrolling for both side.**

Below image can tell u what exactly i want [image: Horizontal Listview]

In the **First image** it is showing 5 items and when scroll the `Listview` it should scroll the items As shown in **Second image** Thanks In Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a closed (circular) ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per your requirement you want **circular/infinite scrolling horizontal list view**,

This is [InfiniteScrollView](https://github.com/satansly/InfiniteScrollView)  which may help.You need to update this library as per your requirement and change *ImageView* to any other view which you want to scroll horizontally.

**Edit - Solution below works for scrolling list view circularly only on one side ::**

Check this [circular-list](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/circular-list-adapter) for implementing a circular list adapter. And as your list view is horizontal check this [library](https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view) to create a custom horizontal list view.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: i want item should scroll from both side.