# how to create closed circular Recyclerview with custom Recycler adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

this might be a possible duplicate , but proper answer is still not available.
 I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview/4940073#4940073) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28492359/circular-recyclerview) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31253555/how-to-create-a-circular-endless-recyclerview)

As stated in the links I wish to implement a recyclerview which is circular ie

[view 1]-[view 2]....-[view N-1]-[view N]-[view 1].....and so on

Since there are no override methods to get View and get Item in recyclerview , I 
am unable to succeed.

please help.Thanks in Advance!

**my recycler adapter code**

```
public class HorizontalRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<HorizontalRecyclerAdapter.ProductViewHolder> {

    List<Product> products;
    private Context mContext;
    ImageLoader imageLoader;


    HorizontalRecyclerAdapter(List<Product> products, Context mContext) {
        this.products = products;
        this.mContext = mContext;

    }

    @Override
    public ProductViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.product_layout, parent, false);
        return new ProductViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ProductViewHolder holder, int position) {

        imageLoader = SingletonRequestQueue.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader();
        String URL = products.get(position).getProductImageUrl();
        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        /* to hide the progress bar after image response */

        imageLoader.get(URL, new ImageLoader.ImageListener() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(ImageLoader.ImageContainer response, boolean isImmediate) {
                if (response != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = response.getBitmap();
                    if (bitmap != null) {
                        holder.progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {}
        });
        holder.itemImage.setImageUrl(URL, imageLoader);
        holder.itemName.setText(products.get(position).getProductName());
        holder.itemPrice.setText("₹ "+products.get(position).getProductPrice());
        holder.sellerLogo.setImageResource(products.get(position).getProductSellerId());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    public static class ProductViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        NetworkImageView itemImage;
        NetworkImageView sellerLogo;
        TextView itemName;
        TextView itemPrice;
        ProgressBar progressBar;


        public ProductViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemImage = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_image);
            sellerLogo = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_seller);
            itemName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_name);
            itemPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.product_price);
            progressBar = (ProgressBar)itemView.findViewById(R.id.network_image_progressbar);


        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked  in a little deep and found a working solution/hack [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29693593/circular-auto-scrolling-horizontalscrollview-android).I have tested it and it works well.I am closing this question. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45114415/4792879). I have tried, it works for recycler view and creates endless scrolling effect from end.