# How to view the list view with the rotation

Tags: android-listview

I am doing an activity with the `listview`.

If the listview contains A B C D E... and if the user scrolls the listview and downloads the first two items of listview will be hidden like this C D E F G...

Hence the hidden item should be viewed at the end of the list like this C D E F G A B (like this). I have to show while scrolling, I don't have any idea about this, please help me.

Please, give some reference or example to implement this function thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create a closed (circular) ListView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I have done this example only but my list rotating too many times but i want to get the list to be rotated like in the numbers in the gaming machine or in the meter box