# Show last element following the first element in an android spinner

Tags: android, android-spinner, android-custom-view

I want to show a spinner like the following image:

[image]

The idea is to show the first element near the last. In the image above, if the user is in the 00 item, he can scroll up to go to the last item (item 59) and if the user is in the last item, he can scroll down to the first element (item 00).

I know that with the android's spinner as it it's not posible so maybe I will have to do my own custom spinner but I want to know if somebody did something like this or if there is a library to use.

I hope let me understand myself.

Comment: Android provides a timepicker AFAIK, can't you use that?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332847/how-to-create-a-closed-circular-listview?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: use this library https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/3899

Comment: Thanks @NavneetKrishna !. This library it's exactly what I wanted.

Comment: @AlphaDeveloper glad that it helped :)